# Python: How to store class object ref in txt file as part of another class objects attributes, for use with importing to populate class object

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm building a game in python.  In it I have a class called Actor.

```
class Actor:
    def __init__(self, *initial_data, **kwargs):
        self.Name = 0  
        self.Weapon = 0

        ...#other attributes

        #This code lets you populate the class attributes using a dictionary
        for dictionary in initial_data:
            for key in dictionary:
                setattr(self, key, dictionary[key])
        for key in kwargs:
            setattr(self, key, kwargs[key])
```

I am using this code in function to populate my class when I call my func.
"Source" is the path directory I provide to my function.

```
with open(Source) as char_data:
    char_stats = dict(filter(None, csv.reader(char_data)))
    # Load in passed in data dummy text file "Source" in place of mysql database into dictionary

    character = Actor(char_stats)
    # Dump the dictionary into a character class

    return character
    # return the filled out character class
```

I am using a simple txt file file to store attribute data

```
Name,Bob
Health,100
Stamina,100
Magic,100
Weight,100
...
Weapon,Sword() #I want to do this but it doesn't work out
```

For now I'm using the txt file in place of a database until I get all the bugs out.  Is there any way to do this? Say I already have a class called Sword() defined. Is there a way to turn the string Sword() into a class object Sword()?  Is there a way to store it into a text file so that when imported python interprets it as class sword and not str"sword()"?

Comment: Don't use a text file & csv reader.  Use a [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)

Comment: sooo in short your suggesting i do something like this.  character = Actor().  character = pickle.load(file) .  I'll try it out thanks!

Comment: Yes - you can even pickle your [classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled).  Your example isn't quite right - you first need to save it, but that's the general idea